# Trying to understand RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure I understand the use of `RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics` in Flutter.

What I have is a listview of variable items (think something like a twitter feed), and those items have images in them which dynamically load.  If an image above your current position loads, then the listview item changes size and the whole list gets pushed down.  The user loses his current position, which is annoying.

Reading the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics-class.html) on `RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics` I thought that it would solve the problem I'm describing.  But its not working for me at all, so either I am misunderstanding what it does or I misused it

Am I understanding what its purpose is?

Comment: Hello @Mark, were you able to fix this?

Comment: @rupinderjeet Unfortunately no.  It seems flutter team is ignoring requests/too busy to address this for now